# Randomly select the tuples from the list: type error

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

y = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
```

I have a list of tuples as follows:

```
xy = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(x,y)]
```

Now I wanted to randomly select 3 position/index of the tuples in the list.

```
random_indices = np.random.choice(len(xy),3,replace=False)
```

Here I applied the indices to return the list of SELECTED tuples:

```
selected_xy = xy[random_indices]
print selected_xy
```

BUT I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    selected_xy = xy[random_indices]
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

My goal is to randomly select the tuples from the list, the expected result should look LIKE as follows:

```
[(1,11),(3,13),(4,14)]
```

What is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert `xy` to a NumPy array, lists only support indexing with integers:

```
>>> xy = np.array([(a, b) for a, b in zip(x, y)])
>>> random_indices = np.random.choice(len(xy), 3,replace=False)
>>> xy[random_indices]
array([[ 7, 17],
       [ 2, 12],
       [ 4, 14]])
```

In Python you can do this using either `operator.itemgetter` or loop over indices in a list comprehension and fetch the item at that index:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> xy = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(x, y)]
>>> random_indices = np.random.choice(len(xy), 3, replace=False)
>>> itemgetter(*random_indices)(xy)
((2, 12), (1, 11), (4, 14))
```

Comment: thanks it works. so numpy does not use list of tuples?

Comment: numpy is better since i am working with a large array in my real case.

Comment: @bercik NumPy will convert those tuples to arrays to support faster operations. You can do: `map(tuple, xy[random_indices])`, but it's not worth it.